# Cache wp-json/posts without a plugin?

Tags: ajax, cache, json

Is there a way to cache the following url on my site without using a plugin?

`www.domain.com/wp-json/posts?type=custom_post_type&filter%5Bposts_per_page%5D=5&filter%5Btaxonomy%5D=events_cat`

My situation doesn't allow me to install caching plugins, so I was wondering if there was a way within the functions.php file or elsewhere that would allow me to cache the results of this?

Comment: Can you provide context as to why caching plugins aren't possible? You don't want any answer to also cause problems for those reasons if you never share them. Is there no object store such as memcache? I also notice you specify the taxonomy, but not the term to filter by

Comment: My hosting provider doesn't allow 3rd party caching plugins.

Comment: That sounds... dubious, I'd strongly recommend changing provider ( and naming them here ). It's likely they've done this to reduce file system accesses so they can fit more people on a server. Considering your API call is for only 5 posts filtered by post type and taxonomy, it should be fast. You're unlikely to get much of a speed boost if you have caching around it ( possibly even be slower if it's file based caching )

Comment: It's actually quite the opposite. They're a high-end provider that offers their own caching system. But for my own edification, I'd like to know if my question is possible.

Comment: hmm in that case you have a problem, WordPress already does some caching here via the object cache, so you'll need to be more specific about what it is you want cached, are you referring to a full page load? What caching storage are you intending to use? Or are you only caching the data not the full response?